# Is it always possible to optimize a multivariate function sequentially?

Tags: nonlinear-programming, convex-optimization, nonconvex-programming

Suppose we have a multivariate function like $f(x,y,z)$ which should be maximized with the constraints $g_i(x,y,z)\le 0 \quad \forall i$. The general rule is to use KKT conditions and derive all KKT points. Here, we determine all variables at the same time and through the same system of equations.

I think another possibility is solve the problem sequentially like $\max_x \max_y \max_z f(x,y,z)$. I am wondering if the sequential approach is always correct and can be implemented? Should the problem be convex to use it or it can be used for non-convex problems, too?

Comment: Isn't this a counter example? Let $f(x,y,z)=xyz$ (or $f=x+yz$, etc) and assume that you are maximizing $f$ over the polyhedral
\begin{align*}
0\le &x\le1 \\
-1\le &y\le 0 \\
-1\le &z\le 0 \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much. Interesting example. In P. 133 Convex Optimization by Boyd, This formula is presented for the minimization problem. I am wondering under what conditions this formula is correct.

Comment: Ok, now that you mentioned the book, I know what you mean. I am writing an answer to the question!

Answer (score 4):

This is possible to do in ***a functional form that preserves all relevant information***. As mentioned in the Convex Optimization by Boyd (page 133, Optimizing over some variables):

> We can always minimize a function by first minimizing
> over some of the variables, and then minimizing over the remaining
> ones. This simple and general principle can be used to transform
> problems into equivalent forms. The general case is cumbersome ...

Consider, for instance, the example that I mentioned in the comments:
\begin{align*}
z^\star = \max~~ xyz\\
\text{s.t.}~~
0\le &x\le1 \\
-1\le &y\le 0 \\
-1\le &z\le 0 \\
\end{align*}

In a procedure similar to the example of the book, we first begin by $x$ and define $z^\star(x)=x \cdot \max yz$ subject to $-1\le y,z\le 0$ which results in $z^\star(x)=x$ with $y^\star = z^\star = -1$. In the next step, we maximize $z^\star(x)$ over $0\le x\le 1$ which gives $x^\star = 1$ and so the general solution is

$$z^\star=1,x^\star=1,y^\star=z^\star=-1$$

This example was simple since variables are not dependent in the constraints. In theory, you can do sequential optimization, but as Boyd and Vandenberghe mention, this is very problem dependent and could see different forms in different problems. There is no need for convexity or even differentiability as long as all information is properly preserved while moving from a subset of variables to the next.

Comment: Mamnoon. You specified an important issue to keep in mind.

Comment: @Katatonia Khahesh:) I polished the answer to make it more similar to the example of the book, but in general, $z^\star(x)$ could itself be a nonlinear nonsmooth function of $x$.